# Trigger AWS Lambda function based on a manifest file which copies files from one S3 bucket to another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which is written in Python. There is an event based trigger and whenever there is a file copied in the source S3 bucket, the Lambda gets triggered and it copies the file to a destination S3 bucket. The files are uploaded to the source S3 bucket manually.

Instead of moving every single file whenever they are uploaded to the source bucket, the Lambda needs to be triggered **only when there is a file called `Manifest.txt` file in the Source bucket**. This `Manifest.txt` file which will be uploaded to the source bucket manually as well, will have a list of file names.

The requirement is that users will upload files to the source bucket and then they will upload the Manifest file with a list of all file names that are uploaded. The Lambda function will need to be triggered only when this Manifest is uploaded to the source bucket and the Lambda function will copy the files that are referenced in the Manifest file to the destination bucket along with the Manifest file.

Could someone please assist how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need fully custom solution for that.

Comment: How does the manifest file get created? Are you saying that you do _not_ want to copy every file when it is created -- instead, you only want to copy the files that are referenced in the manifest file? Is it always the same `manifest.txt` file? If so, when is the file 'emptied', or is it always growing bigger? Also, why do you want to wait for the manifest file rather than simply copying _every_ file? Please Edit your question to add these details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - hey John thanks for the response. I have edited my question and added the details.

Comment: Download the manifest to /tmp, open the manifest, iterate over its contents, and copy the relevant object to the target bucket. Be aware of the time limits for a single Lambda invocation.

Comment: **Side-note:** An AWS Lambda function can be triggered with _multiple_ incoming event records. Your current coded is only looking at the first record (`event['Records'][0]`). This can lead to some events being lost. I recommend you change your code to loop through each incoming record: `for record in event['Records']: key = record['s3']['object']['key']` etc

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to trigger an AWS Lambda function based upon the specific Key (filename) of the object.

However, a common practice is to trigger the Lambda function for *every* object that is uploaded. Then, **have the Lambda function check the Key of the object that was created**. If the Key is *not* the `manifest.txt` object, then simply exit the function. Lambda functions are only charged for the milliseconds that the function runs, so it would be a rather minor cost to perform this check on non-manifest files.

Then, when the Lambda function sees that the Key is `manifest.txt`, it can:

- **Download** the manifest file to the `/tmp/` directory
- **Read** the contents of the manifest file
- **Loop** through each listed key and **copy** the object

As @jarmod points out, it would be a good idea to **increase the Timeout of the Lambda function** to ensure that there is sufficient time for the copy process.

If you have *many* users uploading files and manifest files, then you might have a conflict if they are all trying to write to the manifest file. You might want to **allow *many* manifest files** (eg `username.manifest`) so that each user can upload their own list without interfering with other users.

Comment: Although you could specify the trigger prefix as the full key such as s3://youhadonejob/manifest.txt if you were confident that no-one was going to upload to keys that began with that same prefix.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point @jarmod! If that's the case, then the Lambda function would _only_ trigger for that specific Key.